Закраска пикселей в qt
Как реализовать закраску области в qt.
Нам изначально дана какая-то функция и требуется закрасить область под ней. Я знаю про Qtprinter но не могу понять как реализовать то, что требуется

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html

Задай вопрос ChatGPT может это поможет лучше понять суть.

QPainter::drawPolygon

всем спасибо, разобрался
